# How to add space between elements so they fill their container div?

Tags: css

I want to add space between *spans* so that the leftmost and rightmost spans will be close to the edges of the *inner div*. I've tried to add the following rule, but it had no effect.

```css
span.icon-square {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

span.icon-square:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}

span.icon-square:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

The illustration of what I'm trying to achieve is given below:

[image]
[image]

So, what am I missing?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can do this with `Flexbox` and `justify-content: space-between`.

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #A0C5E8;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

span {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

For Infos and  older browser, `text-align:justify` + a pseudo element to generate an extra line can still be usefull. For really old browser (IE5) , turn the pseudo into a tag (span), technic is quiet old but still efficient **where `flex` is not avalaible or unwanted**.

**edit** : *there is nothing here about `text-justify` if you ever read too fast* ;)

```css
div {
  background:#C3DEB7;
  padding:1px;
}
p {
  background:#A0C5E8;
  margin:1em auto;
  width:80%;
  text-align:justify;
}
p:after {
  content:'';
  width:100%;
}
span, p:after {
  display:inline-block;
}
span {
  border-radius: 15px;
  background:#7A9FC1;
  line-height:60px;
  width:60px;
  margin-top:1em;
  text-align:center;
  color:white;
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 1px ;
}
span:nth-child(1) {
  background:#709AC2;
}
span:nth-child(3) {
  background:#6D93B7;
}
span:last-child {
  background:#948798;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    <span> span</span>
    <span> span</span>
    <span> span</span>
    <span> span</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NNbXEm

Comment: You state "for older browsers", but the majority of usage relative browsers don't support text-align: justify (https://caniuse.com/css-text-justify)

Comment: @RAZERZ you realize it is a five years old post  and that `text-justify` and `text-align` are **two different things ?** https://caniuse.com/?search=text-align text-align is supported for decades everywhere ... My answer never talked about `text-justify`, where did the idea came to you ?

Comment: I misread the caniuse, embarrassing. You're right :)

Comment: @RAZERZ no troubles , i had some doubts about my average english after your comment and did read myself again, i sometimes do not pay much attention nor reread my writing before posting . It happens. :)